# Use WEB Apache server(or any other web server) to read the content generated by a compiled c file (i.e .exe)

Tags: php, c, webserver

so since my webpage makes very complex calculations its VERY important to have it generated with a compiled code, but since im doing it for the web I need a few commands like the one it comes in PHP like $_SERVER (to get for example the IP of the user), $_GET, $_POST    .

if theres already is one web server like this that pass these things for parameter for example it would be easier.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [CGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) is the search keyword you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two basic options:

1. Use [CGI](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html), which is a well supported system for communicating between web servers and scripts/executables.
2. Write a [module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/developer/)

CGI is simple and near universal, but requires a new process to be spawned for each request. There is also FastCGI which is a bit more complicated but lets processes be reused.

Writing a module is significantly more complicated, but provides better performance.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps look at http://www.boutell.com/cgic/?

Answer (score 1):

You can either compile you program as a [CGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface), or bounce your requests through a PHP script and pass whichever values you need in as command line parameters:

```
<?php

  passthru("/path/to/my/binary {$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']} {$_GET['aparameter']} {$_POST['aparameter']}");

?>
```

If you want to go down the CGI route, [start here](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=program+cgi+in+c&meta=)... ;-)